# how to find less than the largest number in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

i want to show the salaries less than the largest number in the table

```
create table instructor(

ID number not null , 
name varchar(20) ,
dept_name varchar(25),
salary number,
primary key (ID)

);

insert into instructor values('10101', 'sirinvasan' , 'comp csi' , '65000');
insert into instructor values('12121', 'wu' , 'finance' , '90000');
insert into instructor values('15151', 'mozart' , 'music' , '40000');
insert into instructor values('22222', 'einstein' , 'physics' , '95000');
insert into instructor values('32343', 'el said' , 'history' , '60000');
```

i tried using

```
select distinct T.salary
from instructor as T , instructor as S
where T.salary < S.salary
```

but it gives me this error  ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a single table scan using analytic functions:

```
SELECT salary
FROM   (
  SELECT DISTINCT
         salary,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) AS rnk
  FROM   instructor
)
WHERE rnk > 1
```

Or, if you want to use a sub-query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       salary
FROM   instructor
WHERE  salary NOT IN (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM instructor);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=533f0d45c1954a99aa9ce68bee58d23f)*

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  Select salary from table where salary < (Select 
   max(salary) from table)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this.  Here is another one.

```
with a as (
select salary
, max(salary) over () as maxsalary
from instructor
)
select distinct salary
from a
where salary < maxsalary
```

Answer (score 1):

In the name of completeness, here is another viable answer:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT i.salary
FROM instructor i
ORDER BY i.salary DESC
OFFSET 1 ROW;
```

I actually like the simplicity of this one.  It is just ordering the query and skipping the first row.  No analytic functions necessary.

DBFiddle Here: ([LINK](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4f1810178c2b51817eb26923edfa0ca9))